# DDD: using infrastructure from application service without creating abstraction in domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I'm following domain driven design in a new project.

I need to validate some data that I'm receiving in my application service. To validate that data I need to make an http request to a third part endpoint. Following DDD, I have implemented that request in Infrastructure layer. The problem I have now is that I don't want to create an abstraction for that implementation in the domain layer because it has nothing to do with any entity or domain logic, it's purpouse consists only to validate the data I'm receiving in the application service. Since application layer should not reference anything from infrastructure layer because is a more inner layer, and I think I should not create an abstraction in domain because doesn't fit well, how can achieve this?

Comment: Looking at your description I may be wrong but you seem to be using the same model as response from the third party api.  you may have to implement a Adapter design pattern or just do the validation in the IS layer without compromising the domain model

Comment: You wouldn't create an abstraction in the domain layer because _"it has nothing to do with any entity or domain logic"_, or _"it doesn't fit well"_... Though this is only your perspective. By giving us more details (like a more detailed description of the components, or some code along with a description of it) we could try to give you our perspective too. At first sight I'd say that the request could be an _infrastructure service_ (abstractly speaking: a `DataOfTypeXValidator`, for ex.), with implementation in the infrastructure and interface in the model.

Answer (score 1):

Infraestructure layer depends on Application layer also.

You can create an abstraction (interface) in Application layer, and implement it in Infraestructure layer.

And you use dependency injection at runtime.